# How to play as the Axis side?

Tags: nintendo-wii, military-madness

On the Turbografx 16 you could play as the Axis side (green) by doing the following:

> At the title screen choose game mode (new game or 1p continue) then hold Select and press Button I.

With the Wii Virtual Console game version, with the Wiimote, I tried pressing "-" and button "1" after choosing new game but it did not work for me.

Anyone know how to play as the Axis side on the Wii version of Military Madness?

Answer (score 1):

According to [gamefaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/tg16/589030-military-madness/faqs/53871), the controller buttons are matched like this for the Wii supported controllers :

> Wii Remote (Hold it sideways):
>
> Control Pad: Move cursor
>
> - 2: Select
> - 1: Cancel
> - +: Pause
> - -: Switch between "Fight and "Surrender" while paused
>
> Wii Classic Controller
>
> Control Pad: Move cursor
>
> - A: Select
> - B: Cancel
> - +: Pause
> - -: Switch between "Fight and "Surrender" while paused
>
> Gamecube controller:
>
> Control Stick: Move cursor
>
> - A: Select
> - B: Cancel
> - Start: Pause
> - Z: Switch between "Fight and "Surrender" while paused

And to play Axis :

> Select 1P continue at the title screen while holding Select.  While
> still holding Select enter the password of the level you want to play
> on.  When the stage starts, you should be in control of the Axis forces
> now.

Since Select is button 2 on the wii remote, looks like you didn't press the good one.